# Emollients to reduce friction during exercise

Tags: weightlifting, gym, health, skin

I've had a lot of skin problems over the last few years as a result of weight training in the gym, due to the friction under my arms.

The doctor suggested I try some kind of emollient before exercising. Is there anything in particular I should look for? Or just anything with 'emollient' written on it?

Comment: When you say "under my arms", can you elaborate on the location of the problem?

Comment: Can you wear a long sleeve workout shirt made of that spandex-like material